# Automatically adding passive listeners to JS events

Tags: javascript

Google Pagespeed is annoying me and docking me points for 'Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve your page's scroll performance.'

OK, simple enough, add {passive:true} to every time you have an event on scroll! But I'm using libraries and WP Plugins also use their own JS so I wont be able to change those.

So is there a way to add, with JS that every time a scroll event is called, that it will always be passive?

Comment: If the plugins you're using are open source, you can submit a PR to fix the problem upstream, and it will benefit everyone who uses that plugin.

Comment: You could monkeypatch `addEventListener`, but that's not a solution, since when an event happens to be active (that you can't check), things go wrong again.

Comment: not without taking a performance hit - but that would be OK because PageSpeed would say the right thing then? Or, don't use third party libraries so you can get PageSpeed to say the right thing. Go here and see what PageSpeed says about `www.google.com`. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.google.com